# How do I convert post request body to query string format on go fasthttp/gofiber?

Tags: go, go-fiber, fasthttp

This is what I'm doing with Get requests

```
app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {


    fmt.Println(string(c.Request().URI().QueryString()))
    
    return c.SendString("Ok!")
  })
```

I'm getting the following output

```
hello=12&sdsdf=324
```

I want to do the same for POST request. I tried `string(c.Body())` but I got output like the following

```
----------------------------948304762891896410291124
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="hello"

ge
----------------------------948304762891896410291124
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ge"

dsfs
----------------------------948304762891896410291124--
```

How can I get a query string format out put for POST. The post parameters can be anything and any number.

Answer (score 3):

You could try `BodyParser` method, the Document Link at https://docs.gofiber.io/api/ctx#bodyparser

```golang
type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name" xml:"name" form:"name"`
}

app.Post("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        p := new(Person)
        if err := c.BodyParser(p); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        log.Println(p.Name)
        return nil
})
```

Comment: In this solution, I should know the list of parameters which is going to come, right? The server doesn't know what all params will be coming.

Comment: Yes, BodyParser requires a struct to parse the body, if you want all params, checkout the MultiPartForm at https://docs.gofiber.io/api/ctx#multipartform